# ADFS SharePoint 2013 site login issue. URL redirecting to same login page on selecting ADFS authentication in dropdown

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, authentication, adfs, ssl

I have installed and configured ADFS server on my virtual machine of SharePoint 2013. And I have followed all the steps as given in the following link,

https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/sharepoint-2013-configure-web-application-for-adfs/

Lastly I had also followed microsoft link regarding ADFS configuration but that also didn't worked, following was the link,

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx

There are also some other links that I followed that didn't helped,

http://sharepointpals.com/post/Configuring-ADFS-as-Authentication-Provider-For-SharePoint-2013-Web-Application

I am kind of stuck to the issue. I had created SSL certificates. Also followed the SharePoint observations link as I have stated above. Also tried installing certificate authority and then creating certificate as stated in the below link,

https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/sharepoint-2013-configure-web-application-for-adfs/

But that too didn't helped. Now I am following above SharePoint observations link, the new error I am getting is that, whenever I try to login using ADFS authentication (ie- when I selected ADFS provider) in the login window of dual authentication. It is again redirecting to the same page. While as by using windows authentication I am able to login to the site. What might be going wrong? Why there are so much hassles while logging to ADFS site using ADFS authentication. Yet after following those many links. Any help would be appreciated. The issue now is I am redirecting to the same dual authentication login page when selecting ADFS provider in dropdown of login page. I am working on SharePoint 2013 Enterprise. Also I am getting error "There is a problem with this website's security certificate". And when I click on "Continue to this website(not recommended" link then it goes to that "Sign In" page where we select authentication type to login.

Comment: Have you configure relying party something like in this link https://blogit.create.pt/miguelmoreno/2014/11/14/configure-adfs-3-0-with-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: NO I have followed relying party as given in this link , https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/sharepoint-2013-adfs-3-0-configure-relying-party/